# How do compilers perform information hiding and encapsulation?

Tags: java, encapsulation, information-hiding

When I create a Java class definition, I can use `private`, `public`, `protected` and other keywords to control how the members and methods are accessed:

```
public class Bowel{
  private Movement privatePoop = new Movement(1);
  public Movement publicPoop = new Movement(2);

  ...
}
```

What does the compiler do differently when it's creating bytecode for the `privatePoop` and `publicPoop` method and member? If someone externally tries to access `privatePoop`, how does it know/signify to the JVM that they shouldn't be able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the compiled classes and members are marked as public, private, etc. It is pure syntactical protection: the compiler won't compile an access to a private member from outside the enclosing class. All this you can bypass at runtime by [reflection](https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial).

Comment: Provided you have the permission to bypass.

Comment: Indeed, reflection you can prevent with a `SecurityManager`. But if you were to write your own compiler...